# Advantages of tiling based instruction selection algorithms with tiles representing more than one machine instruction?

Tags: compiler

In `Modern Compiler Implementation in C` of A. Appel some instruction selection algorithms are discussed based on tiling an intermediate representation tree. Each tile (or tree pattern) expresses **a single machine instruction** as a fragment of an intermediate representation tree.

Are there any variants for the single machine instruction part (e.g.: letting a tile represent **more than one machine instruction**)? And if so, what are their advantages?